# Converting cells in DataGridView to comboboxes and back: is this good code?

Tags: c#, datagridview

In a DataGridView I need to frequently create and destroy comboboxes. I'm worried about effective resource use, possible memory leaks etc. The following toy code converts cells back and forth between textboxes or comboboxes on button clicks, the location chosen in textBox1. Imagine someone pressing the buttons all day converting the boxes back and forth (or maybe another method doing this a few times a second). Will this lead to lots of memory usage or other performance problems? I'm just not sure what DataGridView does with old boxes, not sure I'm getting rid of old stuff correctly. Or does DGV take care of all of this automatically?

Edit: obviously this is *not* the application in mind, but a toy model with functioning code meant to illustrate the issue.

This size of this (100-200) rows is about the size of dgv I'd be dealing with.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataGridViewTextBoxColumn dgcol = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.Controls.Add(dgv);
            dgv.Dock = DockStyle.Right;
            dgv.Columns.Add(dgcol);
            dgv.Rows.Add(100);
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //make a box a combobox
        {
            int row = Int32.Parse(this.textBox1.Text);
            DataGridViewComboBoxCell newcombobox = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
            newcombobox.DataSource = new List<string> { "yellow", "green" };
            this.dgv[0, row].Dispose();
            this.dgv[0, row] = newcombobox;
        }
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)// make a box a textbox
        {
            int row = Int32.Parse(this.textBox1.Text);
            DataGridViewTextBoxCell newtextbox = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();          
            this.dgv[0, row].Dispose();
            this.dgv[0, row] = newtextbox;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _”Imagine someone pressing the buttons all day converting the boxes back and forth.”_ … I can easily imagine that person thinking there must be a better way. Can you supply a larger context on WHY you are doing this and in this particular way? I am just saying that this seems like an awkward UI and I am confident there would be a better/easier way to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Comment: In addition, I would think that when the code executes the lines… `this.dgv[0, row] = newcombobox;` OR … `this.dgv[0, row] = newtextbox;` … that what ever cell was in the grid BEFORE that will just get collected by the Garbage Collector. Even with …. `this.dgv[0, row].Dispose();` … the cell object disposed is going to fall to the whims of the GC. Obviously if you do this many-many times, the GC has to do more work. Therefore, in theory, I am guessing this “could” create a large memory footprint.

Comment: @JohnG , this is toy code, just meant to illustrate the issue. The actual application displays and edits business objects across a data grid view. As those objects are created, edited , deleted or moved around, the need arises for changing redefining the type of various cells.

Comment: Hmm… So, the posted code does/does not represent the actual code, but is “toy” code? I am not sure what “toy” code is, however from a “toy” code perspective to answer your question… _”is this good code?”_ …It appears to work therefore… I would say sure go for it.